# Anchor Links on page not working in Firefox or IE, but do work in Chrome and Safari

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

I have anchor links on a page, jumping you down the page to various sections. For instance:

```
<a href="#pointandshoot">Point and Shoot Cameras</a>
```

And then further down the page:

```
<a name="pointandshoot"></a>
```

There are several different ones on the page.

These work fine in Chrome and Safari on Mac and PC, but do not work at all in Firefox on Mac and PC, or in IE (8) on a PC. They jump a short distance down the page, but not to where they are supposed to.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

After an issue I encountered today it looks like anchor tags with no content don't work in some versions of IE, e.g.:

`<a id="example"></a>`

Putting something inside fixes the problem, e.g.:

`<a id="example">&nbsp;</a>`

Same behaviour whether you use `name` or `id` for the anchor.

I have not tested with Firefox.

Comment: no content in the anchor definitely breaks IE behavior. Note that for IE 10 I had to put &nbsp; 3 times for it to work. Also I redefined the anchors as <a id="example" name="example">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> (the fourth &nbsp; is just in case of IE 11 escalating the problem).

Comment: Using `&nbsp;` fixed it for me on IE 11. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<a href="#pointandshoot">Point and Shoot Cameras</a>
```

always routes to an element with an id on it.

like `<div id ="#pointandshoot"></div>`

Id's has to be unique.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your destination anchors like this:

```
<a id="an_id">Description</a>

<a href="#an_id">Link Text</a>
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: www.w3schools.com has some pretty good HTML and related info. Good CSS reference as well.